# in ajaxified page back button is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax

in my ajaxified page i have used several user control shifting from one user control to anothe r and then pressing the back button takes me to first page instead of previously filtered page
how to solve this
all this filters are linkbuttons i am also using listview these filters are actually filtering the content of this listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [jquery history](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html) plugin. If you are using `UpdatePanel` to perform the AJAX requests you might find [this article](http://aspnetpodcast.com/CS11/blogs/asp.net_podcast/archive/2008/06/15/asp-net-podcast-show-116-using-the-history-functionality-with-the-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-in-net-3-5-service-pack-1-beta-1.aspx) helpful as well as [this video](http://www.asp.net/aspnet-in-net-35-sp1/videos/introduction-to-aspnet-ajax-history).

Comment: darrin according to you which one should be a better approach using jquery plugin or going according to the approach described in video